# Input string not in correct format for bar chart ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I am trying to display a summary page using chart but there seems to be a error and I do not know how to resolve it. When I run the SQL statement, the data will be displayed like this.

|Total| studentResponse |
|  2  |        A        |
|  0  |        B        |
|  1  |        C        |
|  3  |        D        |

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;

public partial class Teacher_Summary : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MySqlConnection myConn;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        chartQn1.Visible = false;
        int quiz = (int)Session["topicID"];
        string question1 = (string)Session["question1"];

        myConn.Open();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        string populateData = "select count(studentResponse) as Total, studentResponse from result where quizID = '" + quiz + "' and questionID = '" + question1 + "' group by studentResponse";
        MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(populateData, myConn);
        sda.Fill(dt);
        myConn.Close();

        string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        double[] y = new double[dt.Rows.Count]; 
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) 
        {
            x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][1]); // <-- this is the error
        }
        chartQn1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);

        chartQn1.Series[0].ChartType = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.SeriesChartType.Column;

    }
    protected void btnDone_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("../Teacher/Questions.aspx");
    }
    protected void btnReveal_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        btnReveal.Visible = false;
        chartQn1.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void chartQn1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

So how am I supposed to do this?
The error that I received is that the input error is wrong for Y.

Comment: First I think you may have flipped the order, try `x[i] = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();` and `y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][0]);`. Second, consider using [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) method, it adds error checking and ensures your code won't crash if invalid double is given.

Answer (score 0):

Check your type

```
y[i] = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[i][1]);
```

Your trying to convert string 'A' to double and others ('B','C','D')